# Flask to Django

Tags: python, django

I am following some nice Flask tutorials and trying to apply some of the code to a Django projects but keep getting hung up on the following:

```
def redeem(self):
    """
    Update the redeem stats for this coupon.

    :return: Result of saving the record
    """
    self.times_redeemed += 1

    if self.max_redemptions:
        if self.times_redeemed >= self.max_redemptions:
            self.valid = False

    return db.session.commit()
```

I'm getting hung up on the `db.session.commit()` at multiple spots. I'm working in Django but appears it is Flask only.

Comment: Why do you use `db.session.commit()`? Django has ORM. You need not to commit SQL on your own.

Comment: @KaiserKatze Flask also uses an ORM (SQLAlchemy) and `db.session.commit()` is how you save an ORM instance. See http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.3/queries/ if you are interested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Django alternative would simply be

```
self.save()
```

See [What happens when you save?](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#what-happens-when-you-save)

That being said, I would suggest following Django tutorials instead. Although similar, Flask and Django has many fundamental differences.